# On click transfer javascript from parent window to be used in child window, window.open

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, window.open

```
 <!--The element of images is the child window. I can get the javascript to work 
   correctly from the child window, but I need the class of the image clicke 
   on from the parent page to effect the child window using window.open.-->

<div class="slides"> 
     <img class="item-1 cardone" src="images/cardone.jpg"/>
     <img class="item-2 cardtwo" src="images/cardtwo.jpg"/>
     <img class="item-3 cardthree" src="images/cardthree.jpg"/>
     <img class="item-4 cardfour" src="images/cardfour.jpg"/>
     <img class="item-5 cardfive" src="images/cardfive.jpg"/>
</div>
```

```
$('.icon-search').click(newWindow);  //targeting the image  

function newWindow(){
  var win = window.open('../carousel/index.html'); //child window
  var script = document.createElement('script');   
  var $this = $(this).prev().attr('class');  //class of image to save for child window

  //script below pertains to only child window
  $("."+newSrc+"").not(this).remove('img');  
  $(this).insertAfter($('.slides img:nth-child(2)')).addClass('item-3');
  $('.slides img:nth-child(1)').removeClass().addClass('item-1'); 
  $('.slides img:nth-child(2)').removeClass().addClass('item-2');  
  script.src = 'pf-js/projects.js';  
  win.document.head.appendChild(script);
 }
```

I need the script to be transferred using window.open, when debugging and checking at the console, no script is transferred.

Comment: Try this : `win.document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);`

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette the script isn't working.. mine didn't look right at the bottom win.document.head.appendChild(script); And from your experience console log should show the new script in the head?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define your script as a string and append it to a DOM node.
Then, you can append this DOM node to the head of the new opened window.

I've made you a simple example on [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/awowQq) which has this code:

*(I only added a button to your HTML to trigger the script.)*
`<button class="icon-search">Icon Search</button>`

**MAKE SURE** that the script you will append is working!!!
`newSrc` was not defined (from what you posted).

```
// Button handler.
$('.icon-search').click(newWindow);  //targeting the image  

function newWindow(){

  // Create a script node
  var script = document.createElement("script");

  // Define the script as a string.
  var scriptText = 
      "alert('Hello World!');"+
      "var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];"+
      "body.style.backgroundColor = 'red';"+
      "body.innerHTML = '<h1>This works!</h1>'";

  // Put the script string inside the script node,
  script.innerHTML = scriptText;

  // Open a new window.
  var newWin = window.open("","_blank");

  // Append the script in head.
  newWin.document.head.appendChild(script);
}
```

Comment: Wow.. I've seen so many explanations of this but never a working script to see exactly how it works.. fantastic! I supplied much as I can to give someone an idea what I was working with is why the newSrc wasn't working.  Also I thought was an easier way  was to call a parent window function from the child window, from your experience is that the easier route?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do... For sure, it would make the script `A` being at only place for many child documents (easier to maintain) and would allow not to care about the single quotes. But you would need a script `B` in child pages to get the script `A`... So this makes 2 scripts to maintain. And that's only ok if the script `A` is also runs on the parent document. You will have to give an `id` to script `A` in order to call its `innerHTML`. **But you could create a separate .js file too!** This would be a better way to go. ;)

Comment: Yes.. thought so, that's how it's originally set up with two different script files. From there call the function from the child window. Struggling.. maybe you know of a link that explains? If not thanks for your help regardless!

Comment: **The best thing is .js files.** *1)* It can be cached by the browser, so it fastens the website loading *2)* The less script you have on client-side, the best it is... Some mobile phones are low on CPU speed. *3)* A script in a child page to load a script from the parent opener... Looks like extra work for nothing. The efficiency certainly isn't the objective. **Why not .js files and simple links instead of "popups"** ? => which are often blocked by browsers by default... Just saying.

Comment: The whole site is links and js files. I have a section where if you click on the photo it opens up a popup with a carousel of photos of that section. What I am trying to do is the photo that is clicked on open up a popup window and that image that is clicked on be first in the popup with the rotating carousel. Hard to explain I suppose. But a popup seemed better than opening a new tab or page with the carousel. Like you said though some browsers don't support.. I might just take a different route.

Comment: Okay... Then look for "modals". Start [here](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/modal/).